# node.js server reading files order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

I have 2 js files in my node.js app

File a defines global object `foo`

In file b I can refer to `foo`.

But if file b is loaded before file a, then an error occurs.

I'm using node's fs module to read the files. I use readdir, and then forEach require on every file. On my system the files are always read alphabetically, so there is never any problem.

Can I depend on those files being read alphabetically?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can sort your array of files by name instead to be sure.

```
fs.readdir(path, function(err, files) {
    files.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
    }).forEach(function(file, key) {
        // stuff
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're working with an array of files, you best bet is to sort the array then work through it; Only starting a new file read when the previous one has completed.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring for the moment the fact that global variables are usually a bad idea...:-)

If you already know the filepaths you need to load, you might wish to use a structure like:

```
var fs=require('fs'),
    vm=require('vm');

/**
 * loads and evals two initialization files in order
 * @param {callback} onComplete  called on init completion
 * @param {callback} on Error    called on error (optional)
 * @return null
 */

function init_app(onComplete,onError){

  var first_filepath  = './file1.js',
      second_filepath = './file2.js';

  // read/eval first file
  fs.readFile(first_filepath,function(first_err,first_result){

    if (first_err) {
      if(onError) {
        onError(first_err.message);
        return;
      }
      else {
        throw first_err;
      }
    }

    // evaluate first result
    try {
      vm.createScript(first_result).runInThisContext();
    }
    catch (e) {
      err_msg='failed to eval source from first file:' + e.type;
      if(onError) {
        onError(err_msg);
        return;
      }
      else {
        throw err_msg;
      }
    }

    // check for existence of foo global
    if(foo == undefined) {
      var msg='foo is undefined after first file read';
      if(onError) {
        onError(err_msg);
        return;
      }
      else {
        throw err_msg;
      }
    }

    // read/eval second (dependent) file
    fs.readFile(second_filepath, function(second_err,second_result){

      if (second_err) {
        if(onError) {
          onError(second_err.message);
          return;
        }
        else {
          throw second_err;
        }
      }

      // evaluate second, dependent result
      try {
        vm.createScript(second_result).runInThisContext();
      }
      catch (e) {
        err_msg='failed to eval source from second file:' + e.type;
        if(onError) {
          onError(err_msg);
          return;
        }
        else {
          throw err_msg;
        }
      }

      // trigger callback
      if(onComplete) onComplete();

    }); // end fs.readFile(second_filepath,...

  }); // end fs.readFile(first_filepath,...

}; // end init_app()
```

Used as:

```
var onComplete = function(){ console.log('init complete'); },
    onError    = function(msg){ console.error(msg); };

init_app(onComplete,onError);
```

Then again, if you only load these files once at the start of your application, you should use require().